# replace everything after a character in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I did some searching and in openoffice and excel it looks like you can simply add an * at the beginning or end of a character to delete everything before and after it, but in Google spreadsheet this isn't working. Does it support this feature? So if I have:

```
keyword USD  0078945jg .12 N N 5748 8
```

And I want to remove USD and everything after it what do I use? I have tried:

```
USD* and (USD*) with regular expressions checked
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The * quantifier just needs to be applied to a dot (.) which will match any character.

[image]

To clarify: the * *wildcard* used in certain spreadsheet functions (eg COUNTIF) has a different usage to the * *quantifier* used in regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you Adam. Hopefully others will find this I couldn't anywhere. I did not want to start using excel for this little thing.

Comment: then how to implement on field so we have a column A that original then column B is using an regexp formatting the value of column A

Answer (score 8):

In addition to options that would be available in Excel (`LEFT` + `FIND`) pointed out by pnuts, you can use a variety of regex tools available in Google Sheets for text searching / manipulation

For example, `RegexReplace`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*)USD.*","$1")
```

- `(.*)` <- capture group `()` with zero or more `*` of any character `.`
- `USD.*` <- exact match on `USD` followed by zero or more `*` of any character `.`
- `$1` <- replace with match in first capture group

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

[image: SO25376275 first example]

and also have a look [at](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-spreadsheet/info).

For spaces within `keyword` I suggest a helper column with a formula such as:

```
=left(A1,find("USD",A1)-1)
```

copied down to suit. The formula could be converted to values and the raw data (assumed to be in ColumnA) then deleted, if desired.

[image: SO25376275 second example]

Comment: Thank you but some of the keywords are two or three words. Is there anyway to remove the USD and everything after it? I can do it in excel right?

Comment: I don't fully understand the update. Can you post a screenshot again or clarify?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers here, you can get into trouble when there are special characters in the text (I have been struggling with this for years).

You can put a frontslash `\` in front of special characters such as `?`, `+` or `.` to escape them. But I still got stuck when there were further special characters in the text. I finally figured it out after reading [find and replace in google sheets with regex](https://twooctobers.com/blog/find-and-replace-with-regex-in-sheets/).

Example: I want to remove the number, period and space from the beginning of a question like this: `1. What is your name?`

Go to **Edit → Find and replace**

In the **Find** field, enter the following: `.+\.`  (note: this includes a space at the end).

Note: In the **Find and replace** dialogue box, be sure to check "Search using regular expressions" and "match case". Leave the **Replace** field blank.

The result will be this text only: `What is your name?`

[image: Screenshot of the process]